# Detect if Lightning component is used in Lightning Out

Tags: lightning-out

Is there a way to detect the context of where component is used?

For example to find if it's LEX, community, app, Lightning Out or Lightning Out Unstyled.

I was thinking something like using $A.getRoot() and then perhaps detecting the interface, but I don't think it's possible.

Alternatively, I can pass a variable to all my children and grandchildren components, but that seems a bit dirty.

Comment: This might help you detect the theme https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2016/04/introducing-ui-theme-detection-for-lightning-experience.html

Comment: @Rao these global variables only work on VF :(

Comment: I see userinfo.getUiThemeDisplayed(), can you not get the theme from apex controller and extend this parent component to create sub components? https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html